# React - localstorage how to add multiple color themes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, local-storage, themes

I have one checkbox that changes the color theme to dark or light. But I want to add three more checkboxes which will also be the color of the page, that is, I want to have 4 checkboxes where the first one will change the page color to black, the second white, the third to green and the fourth to red

**App.js**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

export default function App() {
  const [dark, setDark] = useState(getMode);

  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem("dark", JSON.stringify(dark));
  }, [dark]);

  function getMode() {
    const savedmode = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("dark"));
    return savedmode || false;
  }
  
  return (
    <div className={dark ? "black" : "light"} style={{ height: "100vh" }}>
      <nav>
        <div className="toggle-container">
          <span style={{ color: dark ? "grey" : "yellow" }}>☀︎</span>
          <span className="toggle">
            <input
              checked={dark}
              onChange={() => setDark((prevMode) => !prevMode)}
              id="checkbox"
              className="checkbox"
              type="checkbox"
            />
            <label htmlFor="checkbox" />
          </span>
          <span style={{ color: dark ? "slateblue" : "grey" }}>☾</span>
        </div>
      </nav>

      <div style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>
        <h1>{dark ? "darkmode" : "lightmode"}</h1>
        <p>This is dark mode content</p>
        <h1>The darkmode is implemented by reactjs</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**App.css**

```
.black {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
  }
  .light {
    background-color: blanchedalmond;
    color: black;
  }
  .nav {
    background-color: blue;
    color: white;
  }
  .toggle-container {
    background-color: blue;
    padding: 20px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store the active color to localStorage e.g

```
localStorage.setItem('color', color);
```

set the color based on that:

```
 const [color, setColor] = useState(localStorage.getItem("color"));


  const changeBg = (backgroundColor) => {
    localStorage.setItem('color', backgroundColor);
    setColor(backgroundColor)
  };
```

and use it to set the backgroundColor style:

```
 <div style={{ backgroundColor: color }}>
      <div>
        <label>
          <input
            onChange={() => changeBg("green")}
            type="radio"
            name="background"
          />{" "}
          Green
        </label>
        <label>
          <input
            onChange={() => changeBg("red")}
            type="radio"
            name="background"
          />{" "}
          Red
        </label>
        <label>
          <input
            onChange={() => changeBg("blue")}
            type="radio"
            name="background"
          />{" "}
          Blue
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Another approach whould be to set the *className* instead of style, but you need to define a css rule per color, e.g .red: {...}, .black: {...} etc.

Comment: I can't set the colors, please, if it's not difficult, you could not edit your question using the whole code

Comment: @Synchro I updated my answer. Please, check and let me know if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check the Code on the link below

[Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/billowing-fog-c14w6?file=/src/App.js)

all I did was add

```
const [bg, setBg] = useState("bg-white"); // this will hold classname for background;

const changeBg = (color) => setBg(color);
```

and add it to the App classname

```html
<div className={`App ${bg}`}>
<label>
   <input checked={bg === "dark"} onChange={() => changeBg("bg-red")} /> Dark
<label>
</div>
```

I think the code is straight forward, if you dont understand any thing ask me

Comment: Your code works fine, just having difficulties with the dark mode checkbox, I can easily switch to other modes except the dark mode, for example, if I switch to green, the dark mode remains, that is, the checkbox is not removed from it, could you fix this?

Comment: Check it out  now, i just remove dark state and added  dark mode to the bg

Comment: I checked everything works fine, sorry for the intrusiveness, but I discovered another small problem before when I switched to dark or light mode and refreshed the page, the color did not pass, but now when I switch one of these modes and refresh the page, the color is served, I think this is due to localstorage but this has not happened before

Comment: I was a little unfocused you unfortunately didn't use localstorage that's the problem